# Get post embedded image caption

Tags: posts, images, attachments, media-library, captions

I am trying to get the caption of post embedded images to then use on a lightbox.

This is my code:

```
function my_theme_prefix_content_gallery( $content ) {
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type'=>'image',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
        }
    }

    $pattern     = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox" title="' . $caption . '"$6>';
    $content     = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_theme_prefix_content_gallery' );
```

What i have at the moment(code above) is giving me the caption from other images on the media library. How do I get the caption of the image that I am seeing?

**EDIT**

The Magnific Popup bit for the embedded images popup:

```
 $('a[rel="lightbox"]').magnificPopup ({
        type: 'image',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        fixedContentPos: false,
        removalDelay: 350,
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
});
```

So whit this code I am being able to open post embedded images in Magnific Popup when clicked. All I am missing is a way to show their captions when they open in Magnific Popup.

Comment: On which page you are seeing image ? post, page, CPT, attachment ?

Comment: On the post page, on a lightbox. I just need to get the image caption to show on the lightbox. I have edited my code above to show the whole function where I am trying to implement this functionality.

Comment: Shouldn't $replacement be inside the foreach loop? The $caption value changes inside the foreach loop. Once the loop is done, you will only have the last value of $caption.

Comment: Even with $replacement inside of the loop it keeps giving me the caption from another image from media library..

Comment: Its just frustrating that this seems to be so challenging, unless I am missing something very obvious here.. If I want the post featured image caption its as simple as this **$caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;** but if i want the caption from an image embedded in a post seems to be much more complicated.. Is there some similar function like this for post embedded images I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to add, to every image embedded in a post gallery, a custom rel attribute and a title attribute based on the attachment caption. Instead of parsing the content, you can try to modify the anchor that wraps the images using the `'wp_get_attachment_link'` filter.

```
<?php

    function wpse221533_add_caption_title_to_content_gallery_image_attachments( $markup, $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text ) {

        //Target only images
        if ( ! wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) :
            return $markup;
        endif;

        //Limit the scope of the new attributes
        $post_types = array( 'post', 'page' );

        if ( ! is_singular( $post_types ) ) :
            return $markup;
        endif;

        //Get attachment data
        $current_attachment_object = get_post( $id );

        //Get attachment caption
        $current_attachment_caption = $current_attachment_object->post_excerpt;

        //Nothing wrong with regex, but str_replace is cheaper
        $markup = str_replace( ' href=', ' rel="lightbox" title="' . $current_attachment_caption . '" href=', $markup );

        return $markup;

    }

    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'wpse221533_add_caption_title_to_content_gallery_image_attachments', 10, 6 ) ;

?>
```

**EDIT 16/04/06**

In fact, I didn't understand correctly, since I was referring to posts' image galleries and the op to posts' single image attachments. The code above will only work for galleries.

This other code will do it for single image attachments:

```
<?php

    function wpse221533_add_caption_title_to_content_single_image_attachments( $content ) {

        //Limit the scope of the new attributes
        $post_types = array( 'post', 'page' );

        if ( ! is_singular( $post_types ) ) :
            return $content;
        endif;

        //Parse the content DOM for links
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML( $content );

        $anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'a' ); 

        //Parse each link
        foreach ( $anchors as $anchor ) :

            //Get the rel attribute
            $anchor_rel = $anchor->getAttribute( 'rel' );

            //Get the image ID based on the rel attribute
            $current_attachment_id = substr( strrchr( $anchor_rel, "-" ), 1 );

            //Check if the extracted ID is actually a number
            if ( ! is_numeric( $current_attachment_id ) ) :
                return $content;
            endif;

            //Target only images
            if ( ! wp_attachment_is_image( $current_attachment_id ) ) :
                return $content;
            endif;

            //Get the attachment object
            $current_attachment_object = get_post( $current_attachment_id );

            //Get the attachment caption
            $current_attachment_caption = $current_attachment_object->post_excerpt;

            //Set the rel attribute
            $anchor->setAttribute( 'rel', 'lightbox' );

            //Finally set the title attribute based on the attachment caption
            $anchor->setAttribute( 'title', $current_attachment_caption );

        endforeach;

        //Save the DOM changes
        $content = $doc->saveHTML();

        return $content;

    }

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse221533_add_caption_title_to_content_single_image_attachments', 10, 1 );

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The replacement doesn't seem to be taking place. All I am trying to do is to make post embedded images open on a modal, Magnific Popup in this case. So when I click on a post embedded image I expect it to open in Magnific Popup and show its caption. The code I have above on my question works well apart from the caption bit. I just can't seem to figure out a way to make a post embedded image caption show when this image is open in Magnific Popup, no matter what I try. Edited my code above so you can also see the Magnific Popup bit.

Comment: May it be that your scope is not single page/post views? Try removing the `is_singular` condition.

Comment: No, even removing the `is_singular` condition is not making any difference.. the a tag that wraps the image looks like this `<a href="http://localhost/myteme/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/image.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att=2107"`.. Nothing is changing  `rel="lightbox" title="' . $current_attachment_caption . '"` is not being added.

Comment: The `'wp_get_attachment_link'` filter is tailored for cases like yours, but it's difficult to tell what's going on in your website without knowing your exact setup. Try checking if the filter is passing the `if` conditions and if it's meeting the replacement function. If it's running that function without any effect, you could try substituting the `str_replace` for a proper `preg_replace` or even parsing the link with `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Haven't been around for a while. I have tried your suggestions but I just can't get this to work no matter what I do. So, I think I will leave it for the last touches or even consider to quite trying to implement this as it has been really time consuming so far. It's a shame because I really wanted it to work like that but unfortunately no luck. Thanks anyway

Comment: We were talking about different things. I thought from the beginning you were referring to galleries and not single image attachments. I update the code to reflect a function that might solve the issue.

Comment: You sir are a genius and I would love to pay you a beer! Please let me know how can I send you some money for a couple of cold ones. Thank you so much, works perfectly! ;)

Comment: Nice you got it working finally. I appreciate your offer, but I had fun during the process and the fact that it has helped you is enough reward. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, really! I've been around this for quite a while. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, @Madeirense, I have linked this answer from another question and realized it's not marked as solved. Would you mind selecting the answer as valid so that other users can easily check if the solution works without having to get lost in the comments?

Comment: Sure, sorry my bad. Take care