# Add caption to thumbnails in content

Tags: posts, content, thumbnails, captions

Still trying to get the answer, i don't really know wordpress core (but i'm actually pretty good in PHP), I can't find how to add caption to my images in posts.

I know we can use get_posts to any thumbnail outside it, but inside i need to custom "the_content()" display.

Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

Thanks !
Matthieu

Comment: It is not very clear what are you asking. Thumbnails are not used in content, so what is exactly the question?

Comment: You don't need any special coding for image caption, if you add caption/desc in while uploading or by editing image, that will automatically adds caption to the image

Comment: Are you asking about thumbnail caption ?

Comment: Are you trying to output the caption in the loop or programatically from a custom made function? Are you referring to the featured image or to all the images attached to a post? If it's the last case for both answers, I have just answered the question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221533/get-post-embedded-image-caption/221561#221561

Comment: I want images (thumbnail of not) in my content (when you call the_content() or get_the_content()) to be rendered like this :
<figure>
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
  <figcaption>Caption / Description</figcaption>
</figure>

My question is also about practices on Wordpress, how should we process/modify the content ? With a filter ? If yes how ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <figure>
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr ); ?>
  <figcaption>here goes your caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

for the_post_thumbnail check : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: I'm sorry but my question seems not to be clear, i will manage to be more accurate in previous post.